# Can I print the "description" field of an RPM package info in one line only

Tags: linux, format, rpm

I need to get info of some RPM package and then parse them, so I use the `rpm -q --qf [FORMAT] [PACKAGE]` command.

It is working fine but the description field of the package is always on multiple lines and it is making my job more difficult for parsing. Is there a way to get this field on one line only with a specific format?

Here is my current format string: `Name:%{NAME}\nVersion:%{VERSION}\nRelease:%{RELEASE}\nArchitecture:%{ARCHITECTURE}\nInstall Date:%{INSTALLTIME:date}\nDescription:%{DESCRIPTION}\n`

Comment: I think you mean the "Summary" field, not the "Description" field

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid that the answer is no, you cannot have it on one line. The description is multiline text and the new line characters are put there by package maintainers.

Comment: Yes that's what I was expecting, but I was hoping for some trick or something. I will deal with it anyway thank you

Comment: You can pipe the output of the %description a queryformat  to tr(1) or sed(1) to change new lines to spaces. Rpm also has a --pipe option that can be used with a popt alias to hide the details behind an rpm CLI option.